# No muestra resultado de consulta en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, php7

Cuento con la siguiente tabla llamada "respuestas" en mysql:

```
   id  |   pin   | respuesta1 | respuesta2 | respuesta3
    1     BC3CB       2             3            2
    2     BC3CB       0             1            2
    3     BC3CB       0             1            3
    4     BC3CB       2             1            3
```

Y trabajo con la siguiente consulta para sumar el valor de los datos de la columna respuesta1:

```
SELECT SUM(respuesta1) FROM respuestas
```

El caso es que cuando ejecuto directamente la consulta en phpmyadmin me arroja el valor correcto que es 4, pero al almacenarla en una variable en mi página de php para imprimir el valor, este siempre me manda "1".

Este es mi código PHP:

```
<?php
 $host = "localhost";
 $user = "root";
 $clave = "";
 $bd = "ceustionario";
 $conectar = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$clave,$bd);

 $suma = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT SUM(respuesta1) FROM 
 respuestas");
 $totalsuma = mysqli_num_rows($suma);
<?



<html>
 <div>
  <h1> El valor de la suma es:</h1><br> 
  <?php echo $totalsuma; ?> //Esto siempre me marca "1" y no "4" como en 
                                                              PHPMYADMIN
 </div>
</html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Paso 1:** Te falta agregarle un alías a la columna calculada, para que por medio de ese recuperes dicho valor así:

Asignar alias

```
SUM(columna) AS alias
```

Escribir la consulta

```
$suma = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT SUM(respuesta1) AS Sumatoria FROM 
 respuestas");
$Total = mysqli_fetch_assoc($suma);
```

**Paso 2:** Y ahora para obtener dicho alias haces lo siguiente, la variable y entre corchetes el nombre del alias que indicaste

```
<?php echo $Total['Sumatoria']; ?>
```

**Paso 3:** Honestamente no veo la necesidad de usar `mysqli_num_rows` ya que este método sirve para obtener el número de filas de una consulta, por eso vez 1, entonces remueve dicha línea y lo demás manejalo como te sugiero en mi respuesta.

Te dejo el enlace de [`mysqli_num_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php), para que estudies mas su funcionamiento y cheques que en este caso no lo ocupas.

Comment: Lo intente amigo pero cuando trato de imprimir <?php echo $suma['Sumatoria']; ?>  me arroja este error en esa linea:                                                                                    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Comment: @SuriGang'sHallen he comprobado el ejemplo, con la edición que hice ya te debe funcionar

Comment: Muy buena aportación @Aprendiz gracias, yo aconsejaría que cambies tu Alias de nombre por que tu ya no eres Aprendiz eres un buen maestro.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que corregir, la forma correcta es la siguiente:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <?php

            $suma = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT any_value(SUM(r.respuesta1)) respuesta1 FROM respuestas r GROUP BY r.pin");
            $totalsuma = mysqli_fetch_array($suma); 
            ?>
            <h1> El valor de la suma es:</h1><br> 
            <?php echo $totalsuma['respuesta1']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Complementando, para tu caso usaste $conectar, en mi caso siempre uso $conexion

Comment: Me funcionó muy bien @IngMorales muchas gracias, pero aún no entiendo la función de any_value

Comment: La función ANY_VALUE es para agrupamiento, te resumo para evitar problemas de los mismos, pero puedes omitirla, la uso por buena práctica. Pues para evitar el error 1055.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITO LA RESPUESTA:**

bueno si tu deseas sumar todos los elementos de una columna porque no usas la funcion sum() DE MySql, te dejo un ejemplo:

tu puedes implementar esta funcion MySql:

```html
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Que en PHP es algo asi:

```html
$result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(value) AS value_sum FROM codes'); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$sum = $row['value_sum'];
```

Explicare un poco el codigo:
como vez creo un SELECT y agrego la funcion SUM  y en value debes agregar el valor ID en tu caso y despues selecciono la tabla de donde quiero hacer la consulta y despues sencillamente imprimes el row en un echo,etc.

De acuerdo con la respuesta de [flinsch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480304/flinsch)

Comment: ¿Y la suma que el OP requiere donde quedó?

Comment: A que te refieres? el codigo basicamente realiza un consulta a la base de datos despues verifica si  el resultado no es valor 0 o algo similar a a eso y de despues se almancena la consulta  y luego se imprime.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Comment: ya vi bien voy a editar la respuesta

Comment: Muchas Gracias @simon