# Cómo mostrar una imagen después de una consulta en PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, condiciones

Tengo la siguiente consulta almacenada que me muestra el valor de una suma de datos de la columna respuesta1:

```
$suma = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT SUM(respuesta1) FROM 
respuestas");
$total = mysqli_fetch_assoc($suma);
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para hacer una comparación de este valor y mostrar una imagen alojada en mi servidor? POR EJEMPLO:

Si el valor de $totalsuma es mayor a 5 que muestre rojo.jpg
dentro de etiquetas html y si es menor a 5 que muestre amarillo.jpg que la muestre de igual forma en html

Comment: La primer recomendación que te hago como al usuario de esta pregunta que usa una consulta idéntica a la tuya, si deseas utilizar el valor de la sumatoria generada, entonces no hay necesidad de `mysqli_num_rows`, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291180/no-muestra-resultado-de-consulta-en-php/291185#291185

Comment: Disculpa, a que usuario te refieres?

Comment: al autor de la pregunta que expongo en el enlace

Comment: Es verdad que las consultas son identicas, incluso con los mismo campos. Entonces voy a corregirlo como lo tiene este usuario.

Comment: la ruta a la imagen la tienes almacenada en la base de datos? o solo esta en tu servidor la imagen?

Comment: La tengo almacenada en una carpeta en mi proyecto y no estoy segura si la forma correcta sea almacenar una ruta en mi base de datos, se podrá desde el servidor?

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tienes el código junto al html el código quedaría así:

```
    $suma = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT SUM(respuesta1) AS sumatoria FROM respuestas");
        $total =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($suma);
/*la función fetch_asscoc retorna un array asociativo ["key"=>valor], en donde la llave del valor es el nombre de columna, por lo que al usar "AS sumatoria" en la query le estas diciendo a la consulta que la columna resultante la llame sumatoria, nombre que usaras para acceder a tu valor*/
        if($total['sumatoria']<5){
          //creas una variable que almacene el nombre del fichero o la ruta completa en 
          //este caso es $ruta
          $ruta="amarillo.jng";
        }else{
           $ruta="rojo.jpg"
        }
       ?>
        <!--este div solo es para abstraer el posible código que tienes no es necesario 
         que este en tu código-->
       <div>
         <!--en el src colocas la ruta de directorios en donde se encuentran las imágenes y 
          justo donde iría el nombre del archivo abres un scrip php y colocar la variable que 
           posee el nombre del archivo con un echo para que imprima lo que contiene la 
           variable, que en este caso es $ruta-->
         <img src="../images/<?php echo $ruta; ?>"
       </div>
```

Comment: De hecho es al contrario no usarlo, no tiene caso pues trata de recuperar el valor de la suma y no el número de filas producto de la consulta

Comment: tienes razón me di cuenta después de publicar mi respuesta por ello ya la modifique, por lo que entiendo no puede acceder al valor de la sumatoria de la consulta para poder hacer su condición, no?

Answer (score 0):

si ya tienes el valor de la suma solo faltaría que hicieras la comparación desde PHP.

```
If($total != 5 ){
   if($total > 5)
       echo "<img src='rojo.jpg'>";
   else
       echo "<img src='amarillo.jpg'>";
}
```

Las rutas solo son a manera de ejemplo, lo mejor es que uses rutas relativas en lugar de absolutas, sobre guardar la ruta de la imagen en la BD solo es recomendable si vas almacenar distintas imágenes para cada tupla.